# front luggage carrier for a single speed bike

Tags: single-speed, luggage

I built a Single speed bike based on a old Road bike frame.
What I want to do is to install a luggage carrier to the front for some daily transports (because i like the retro look of those carriers).
But I don't want it to be permanently installed on my bike if there's any way.

So, does anyone know a possibility for a (removable) luggage carrier for a Road bike frame?

Comment: Could you clarify what you're trying to carry? Depending on what you need, a large removable handlebar bag may be a possibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd have a look at http://store.velo-orange.com/index.php/accessories/racks-decaleurs.html
A "decaleur" is a removable handlebar bag mount. You'll still need a (non-removeable) rack for support too though, but for a retro look and larger bag capacity than without a rack, it's a possibility.

Comment: pretty cool! exactly what i was looking for!

Comment: Velo Orange have rearranged their site, try
https://velo-orange.com/collections/rack-hardware-and-accessories/products/vo-decaleur-bag-mount-6mm-posts
(or https://velo-orange.com/products/vo-randonneur-front-rack-with-integrated-decaleur for rack with decaleur)

Comment: https://velo-orange.blogspot.com/2019/01/decaleurs-what-are-they-and-what-do.html

Answer (score 2):

Removable makes it unsafe, as it will jump up and down while riding, unless you can get any type of carrier that has a proper lock thingy.
Use a lid or straps to keep your stuff in the carrier, for that same reason, they jump like mad!

Comment: I agree.  Maybe a large handlebar bag will work (though even that is dangerous if overloaded), but a front rack needs to be REALLY firmly mounted, and a removable rack just won't do that unless a lot of extra care goes into the design.